# UCMA How to detect call ring duration and transfer call before busy signal and terminate?

Tags: c#, ucma

I have a b2b call with self transfer. If there is no answer or agent becomes busy and can not answer the call I want to redirect to another free agent. I s subscribed to ProvisionalResponseReceived for the outgoing call leg and also to StateChanged. So I can see when call is ringing and when it transition from ringing to terminating. How can I deflect/forward this call to another agent before call enters terminating state.Is there any way to calculate ring duration? Or set a limit for ringing before I can transfer it further?

```
// Create the outbound call between UCMA and the agent.
        _outboundAVCall = new AudioVideoCall(_outboundConversation);
        // Register for notification of the StateChanged event on the outbound call. 
        _outboundAVCall.StateChanged += new EventHandler<CallStateChangedEventArgs>(outboundAVCall_StateChanged);
        _outboundAVCall.ProvisionalResponseReceived += new EventHandler<CallProvisionalResponseReceivedEventArgs>(OnOutProvisionalResponseReceived);
        //_outboundAVCall.

        InitiateBackToBackCall(incomingCall, _outboundAVCall);

        _outboundCallLeg = new BackToBackCallSettings(outboundCall, _destinationSipUrit);

        incomingCall.StateChanged += new EventHandler<CallStateChangedEventArgs>(inboundAVCall_StateChanged);
        incomingCall.ProvisionalResponseReceived += new EventHandler<CallProvisionalResponseReceivedEventArgs>(OnInProvisionalResponseReceived);

        // incomingCallLeg.StateChanged += OnCallStateChanged;

        // Create a new conversation for the incoming call leg.
        _inboundConversation = new Conversation(incomingCall.Conversation.Endpoint);

        _inboundCallLeg = new BackToBackCallSettings(incomingCall);

        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Status of incomming call:" + incomingCall.State.ToString());
        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Status of incommoutgoing call:" + outboundCall.State.ToString());

        // Create the back-to-back call instance.
        // Note that you need a Destination URI for the outgoing call leg, but not for the incoming call leg.
        _b2bCall = new BackToBackCall(_inboundCallLeg, _outboundCallLeg);
        // Begin the back-to-back session; provide a destination.
        try
        {
            IAsyncResult result = _b2bCall.BeginEstablish(BeginEstablishCB, _b2bCall);
            /* IAsyncResult result = _b2bCall.BeginEstablish(
                delegate(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                _b2bCall.EndEstablish(ar);
                _waitForB2BCallToEstablish.Set();
            }, _b2bCall);*/
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "_b2bCall must be in the Idle state." + ioe.Message.ToString(),1);
        }
        _waitForB2BCallToEstablish.WaitOne();
```

Comment: I found that I have to catch the not answer or busy answers and try to retreive the call. I have tried the following code: ``

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the code to handle the exception that will occur

```
 private void SelfTransferCompleted(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Exception exceptionCaught = null;
           // bool exceptionEncountered = true;
            try
            {
                _flow.Call.EndTransfer(asyncResult);
                //Self Transfer has completed. successfully.
                exceptionEncountered = false;
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Menu Ended self tranfer for call>" +_flow.Call.CallId);
                // cleaning up atten
                string sqlstring = "update astsxqueue set uniqueid ='" + _server.b2bCallDelId + "' where uniqueid='" + _flow.Call.CallId + "';";
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, sqlstring);
                _server.mconnector.Mysqlqueryruner(sqlstring);

            }
            catch (OperationTimeoutException orte)
            {
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted Operation Timeout Exception: " + orte.ToString(), 2);
                exceptionCaught = orte;
                exceptionEncountered = true;
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Trying to transfer to other agent...", 2);
                RetrieveCallAfterTransferFailure();
                //_flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", null/*transferOptions*/, this.SelfTransferCompleted, _flow.Call);
                // _inboundAVCall.Flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", _server.EndTransferCall, _inboundAVCall.Flow.Call);
                //_flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", _server.EndTransferCall, _flow.Call);
                // Wait for the call to complete the transfer.
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Waiting for transfer to complete...");
                _server._waitForTransferComplete.WaitOne();
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Transfer completed.");

            }


            catch (FailureResponseException frte)
            {
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Failure Exception = {0}" + frte.ToString(), 2);
                exceptionCaught = frte;
                exceptionEncountered = true;
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Trying to transfer to other agent...", 2);
                //_flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", null/*transferOptions*/, this.SelfTransferCompleted, _flow.Call);
                // _inboundAVCall.Flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", _server.EndTransferCall, _inboundAVCall.Flow.Call);
                //_flow.Call.BeginTransfer("tel:+123456", _server.EndTransferCall, _flow.Call);
                // Wait for the call to complete the transfer.
                RetrieveCallAfterTransferFailure();
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Waiting for transfer to complete...");
                _server._waitForTransferComplete.WaitOne();
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Transfer completed.");

            }

            catch (RealTimeException rte)
            {
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Realtime Exception = {0}" + rte.ToString(),2);
                exceptionCaught = rte;
                exceptionEncountered = true;
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR SelfTransferCompleted  Trying to transfer to other agent...", 2);
                RetrieveCallAfterTransferFailure();
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Call is retreived waiting a bit...", 2);
               // Thread.Sleep(2000);
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Call is retreived time passed...", 2);
               // _flow.EndHold(null);

             //   _speechSynthesizer.Speak("We did not get to a green agent. Please retry your option!");  //TEXT TO SPEEECH!
              // SpeakMenuOptions();
             // toneController.ToneReceived += toneController_ToneReceived;
                // Wait for the call to complete the transfer.
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Waiting for transfer to complete...");
                //_server._waitForTransferComplete.Set();
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "Transfer completed.");

            }

        }
        private void RetrieveCallAfterTransferFailure()
        {
            // Take the call off of hold after a transfer fails.
            LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Trying to retrive from Self transfer ...", 2);

            try
            {
                _flow.BeginRetrieve(retrieveResult =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR  Trying to retrive from Self transfer ...", 2);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        _flow.EndRetrieve(retrieveResult);

                        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR  Successfully retrieved call. Waiting a bit");
                        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Call is retreived time passed...", 1);
                        //_flow.EndHold(retrieveResult);
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
           //             _flow.EndRetrieve(retrieveResult);
               //         _speechSynthesizer.Speak("A green agent is busy. Please retry your option!");  //TEXT TO SPEEECH!
                 //       SpeakMenuOptions();
                   //    toneController.ToneReceived += toneController_ToneReceived;


                    }
                    catch (RealTimeException rtex)
                    {
                        LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR  Failed retrieving call." + rtex);
                    }
                },
                null);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ioex)
            {
                LogHelper.Log(LogTarget.FileEvent, "IVR Failed retrieving call."+ ioex);
            }
        }
```

After adding the above code I get it working.

Thanks.